# Have an image follow your finger along the x axis, but have a fixed y-coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using the touchesMoved method to have an image "follow" someone's finger along the bottom of the screen. So the image will follow the x position of the finger, but it ignores the y position and stays vertically-fixed at the bottom (but not horizontally-fixed). Is there some way I can implement this?

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create basket image that will be shown on the screen
    basketView = [[UIImageView alloc]
    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bucket.png"]];
    basketView.frame = CGRectMake(130.0, 412.0, 50.0, 50.0);
    [self.view addSubview:basketView];
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get current touch location
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    // update location of the image
    basketView.center = point;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintain the y position, change the x

```
basketView.center = CGPointMake(point.x, basketView.center.y);
```

Answer (score 1):

In touchesMoved Do this

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get current touch location
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    // update location of the image
    basketView.center = CGPointMake(point.x,basketView.center.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows...

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        // get current touch location
        UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        point.y=basketView.center.y;   //Fix 'y' of basket
        // update location of the image
        basketView.center = point;
    }
```